# Setting a foreign key to more than one table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012

I have three tables Teachers, Student, ViewType

```
table Teachers{
  Id uniqueidentifier, 
  Name nvarchar
}


table Student{
  Id uniqueidentifier, 
  Name nvarchar
}


table ViewType{
  Id uniqueidentifier, 
  Type String
}
```

Note: Let's say for the example that ViewType is not a regular look up table.
it contains data of how to present the Teacher or Student in the ui therefor shouldn't be in the Teacher or Studenttable model.

Is there a way to create a foreign key to two tables where a key is enforced to from 
and only from the two tables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with Declarative Referential Integrity constraints.

You would have to implement this with triggers; and you would need them on all three tables (`insert` + `update` on `ViewType`, `delete` + `update` on the others).

You could put the constraints the other way:

```
alter table Student add constraint FK foreign key (Id) references ViewType (Id)
alter table Teachers add constraint FK foreign key (Id) references ViewType (Id)
```

It isn't perfect (you could end up with a Student & Teacher referencing the same Id, which you would have to deal with), but it's probably the best you could do.